# How can I replace some values in a string that contains backslashes using C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
var topic = "<option value=\"123\">X</option>\r\n  <option value=\"456\">XX</option>\r\n";
```

And a string that looks like this:

```
var topicValue = "456";
```

Is there a way that I can create a new topic string that looks like the following when the topicValue matches:

```
var topic = "<option value=\"123\">X</option>\r\n  <option value=\"456\" selected=\"selected\" >XX</option>\r\n";
```

What I am not sure of is how to create a regular expression that will work with the backslashes that are in my 
topic string. Also is there an easier way to do this than using a regulare expression?

Comment: you can just replace "option value=\\\"<your value here>\\\"" with the same followed by "selected=\\\"selected\\\".

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not sure of the best syntax. Should I use a regulare expression or is there a different way?

Comment: for the supposed approach probably string.replace is just sufficient. that is _string.replace("option value=\\\"456\\\"", "option value=\\\"456\\\"" selected=\\\"selected\\\"")_. Of course you can make it more flexible by passing the number as a variable.

Comment: @ChriPf - Do I need to do topic.replace? Can you put this as an answer with the variable so I can accept and close the question. Thanks very much.

Comment: hmmm... - the actual solution was supposed by @MichaelGraczyk, so I'd rather give the credit to him.

Comment: @Gemma I changed the strings in your question to what I believe you were trying to represent.  Notice the "@" symbol to indicated that the following literal contains no escapes (except the double ").

Answer (score 3):

It's never a good idea to manipulate an XML as a string. it looks like you have a part of an XML in `topic`. Why don't you treat it like an XML. First let's make it a valid XML, just to work with.

```
        <options>
              <option value=\"123\" isSelectd=\"false\">X</option>
              <option value=\"456\" isSelectd=\"false\">XX</option>
        </options>
```

Root node `<options>` is added here and also a new attribute `isSelectd` which is initially false for both child nodes. The node have value of `456` should be searched and updated. Now using the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class you can easily achieve what you want like this.

```
        var topic = "<options>" + 
               "<option value=\"123\" isSelectd=\"false\">X</option>" +
               "<option value=\"456\" isSelectd=\"false\">XX</option>" + 
               "</options>";

        int selectedValue = 456;

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(topic);
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes[0].Value.ToString());
            if (value == selectedValue)
                node.Attributes[1].Value = "ture";
        }

        topic = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
```

topic now contains the following XML,

```
        <options>
              <option value=\"123\" isSelectd=\"false\">X</option>
              <option value=\"456\" isSelectd=\"true\">XX</option>
        </options>
```

Comment: The OP was not working with valid XML because it contains backslash escaped quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as just how it is was written. For example:

```
        string myString = "My name is \"John\"";
        Console.WriteLine(myString);
        myString = myString.Replace("\"John\"", "\"Jony\"");
        Console.WriteLine(myString);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Try code below to achive what you want:

```
        string topic = "<option value=\"123\">X</option>\r\n  <option value=\"456\">XX</option>\r\n";
        Console.WriteLine(topic);
        string topicValue = "456";
        string mustBeReplaced = string.Empty;
        string replaceResult = string.Empty;

        if (topic.Contains(topicValue))
        {
            mustBeReplaced = "value=\"" + topicValue + "\"";
            replaceResult = mustBeReplaced + " selected=\"selected\"";
            topic = topic.Replace(mustBeReplaced, replaceResult);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(topic);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I am trying your way but I get an error: object' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload - any ideas?

Comment: can you replace "var topic" with "string topic" and try again?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the code.  Note that this only works if the whitespace and formatting is consistent:

```
var topic = // topic here

const string optionFormat = @"<option value=\""{0}\""";

var topicValue = // topic value here

var topicToReplace = String.Format(optionFormat, topicValue);
var replaced = topic.Replace(topicToReplace , topicToReplace + @" selected=\""selected\""");
```

Comment: I think you should remove "@" sign and write "<option value=\"{0}\""

Comment: @AdilMammadov Those are two different strings.